# How to make process.stdout.write work in mocha environment?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

My script is using `process.stdout.write` to generate output. It requires to use `process.stdout.write` over `console.log` because `console.log` forces `EOL`.

```
describe('process.stdout.write', () => {
    it('prints "foo"', () => {
        process.stdout.write('foo');
    });
});
```

prints:

```
process.stdout.write
    ✓ prints "foo"

1 passing (5ms)
```

Notice that "foo" is not being printed.

Answer (score 0):

`process.stdout.write` conflicts with `mocha` internal logic for printing the reports.

To get an output of `process.stdout.write` overwrite the `process.stdout.write`, buffer the input and use `console.error` to print the output (`console.log` will not work when `process.stdout.write` is overwritten), e.g.

```js
describe('process.stdout', () => {
    let processStdoutWrite,
        processStdoutWriteBuffer,
        overwriteProcessStdoutWrite,
        resetProcessStdoudWrite,
        getProcessStdoutBuffer;

    /**
     * @var {function} Reference to the original process.stdout.write function.
     */
    processStdoutWrite = process.stdout.write;

    /**
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    overwriteProcessStdoutWrite = () => {
        processStdoutWriteBuffer = '';

        process.stdout.write = (text) => {
            processStdoutWriteBuffer += text;
        };
    };

    /**
     * @returns {string}
     */
    getProcessStdoutBuffer = () => {
        return processStdoutWriteBuffer;
    };

    /**
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    resetProcessStdoudWrite = () => {
        process.stdout.write = processStdoutWrite;
    };

    beforeEach(() => {
        overwriteProcessStdoutWrite();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        resetProcessStdoudWrite();
    });

    describe('.write()', () => {
        it('prints "foo"', () => {
            process.stdout.write('foo');
            process.stdout.write('bar');

            console.error(getProcessStdoutBuffer());
        });
    });
});
```